# Gulp and relative paths issue

Tags: css, sass, gulp, relative-path

I have this gulp task for my scss to css build (including merging with stand-alone .css files of other libraries):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
scss = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    merge = require('merge-stream'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat-css'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');


gulp.task('scss', function () {
    var sass, css;

    sass = gulp.src('./scss/**/[^_]*.?(s)css')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(scss({
             includePaths: [
                'node_modules/slick-carousel/slick'
            ]
        }).on('error', scss.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            flexbox: true,
            grid: true,
            browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 5 years', 'Firefox > 20']
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write());

    // Add all the external css files
     css = gulp.src([
         'styles/styles-src/foxholder.min.css'
     ]);

    // Merge to styles.css and output to src
    return merge(sass, css)
        .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./styles/'));
});
```

And everything is OK with it, except one thing.

If I put in my scss file styles with relative path, like that:

```
div {
  background: url("/assets/icons/checked.svg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

it will be converted to css like this:

```
div {
  background: url(../../assets/icons/checked.svg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

And these '../..' driving me insane: I don't know why my relative paths are changed like this during the scss to css conversion and how to prevent it.

I'll be so glad if someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue was with **gulp-concat-css**. It rebased relative URLs by default. To turn off this option we need to add:

```
.pipe(concat('styles.css', {rebaseUrls: false}))
```

And after that all the URls will no be changed.